# How do you find all scope names for a given class in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

For example, given I defined scopes for the class Task, is there a way to find all scope names for that class?

I'm looking for something like:

```
Task.scope_names
```

which would output something like:

```
["completed", "uncompleted", "pending"]
```

Any ideas on how to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [`docs`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope) such methods as

```
Model.scopes 
#=> outputs all scopes
```

and

```
Model.send(:valid_scope_name?, scope_name)
#=> takes scope name as an argument and returns either true or false
```

are no longer available since Rails 3.1.0.

Comment: Thank you Andrey! That's unfortunate :(